# Deriving the expression for one body density

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-spin, density-operator, many-body, density-functional-theory

My textbook (Richard M. Martin - Electronic structure) has the following equation for the one body density of a system of $N$ electrons:
$$
\langle \Psi | \Psi \rangle n(r) = \langle \Psi | \hat n(r) | \Psi \rangle = N \int \sum_{\sigma_1} |\Psi(r,r_2,\cdots,r_N)|^2 dr_2\cdots dr_N, \qquad \hat n(r) = \sum_{i=1}^N\delta(r - r_i)
$$

How do I arrive at this expression, and what is $\sigma_1$ (?), my Dr Martin doesn't specify. Here is my attempt

$$
\langle \Psi | \hat n(r) | \Psi \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^N\ \int \delta(r - r_i)|\Psi(r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_{i-1},r_i,r_{i+1},\cdots r_N)|^2 dr_1\cdots dr_i\cdots dr_N, \\
 = \sum_{i=1}^N\ \int \Psi(r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_{i-1},r,r_{i+1}, \cdots r_N)|^2 dr_1\cdots dr_{i-1}dr_{i+1} \cdots dr_N
$$
As the particles are electrons, $|\Psi|^2$ is symmetric so I can permute the arguments of $|\Psi|^2$ obtaining
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\ \int |\Psi(r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_{i-1},r,r_{i+1}, \cdots r_N)|^2 dr_1\cdots dr_{i-1}dr_{i+1} \cdots dr_N \\
= \sum_{i=1}^N\ \int |\Psi(r, r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_{i-1},r_{i+1},\cdots,r_N)|^2 dr_1\cdots dr_{i-1}dr_{i+1} \cdots dr_N
$$
Finally by renaming the integration variables
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\ \int |\Psi(r, r_1,r_2,\cdots,r_{i-1},r_{i+1},\cdots,r_N)|^2 dr_1\cdots dr_{i-1}dr_{i+1} \cdots dr_N \\
=\int |\Psi(r, r_2,r_3,\cdots,r_N)|^2 dr_2 \cdots dr_N \sum_{i=1}^N 1
$$
So all in all I have
$
\langle \Psi | \Psi \rangle n(r) = \int |\Psi(r, r_2,r_3,\cdots,r_N)|^2 dr_2 \cdots dr_N \sum_{i=1}^N 1 \\
= N\int |\Psi(r, r_2,r_3,\cdots,r_N)|^2 dr_2 \cdots dr_N
$
As you see, I arrive at a different formula. So my questions are:

- What is $\sum_{\sigma_1}$ shorthand notation for? I suppose it has got to do with spin somehow, but I have never seen this notation before
- And why do I not arrive at the desired conclusion?

Comment: Perhaps $\sigma_1$ stands for spin quantum number?

Comment: 9 months no answer is a long time, try Materials Modeling SE: https://materials.stackexchange.com